# Selenium not requiring ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I made a simple Selenium script below in Python. This script runs perfectly for me, even though I don't specify the location of ChromeDriver (and as far as I can tell, I don't even have ChromeDriver installed). All other examples I've seen of simple Selenium programs require the user to specify the location of ChromeDriver.

Why does it not require ChromeDriver here?

```
from selenium import webdriver

website_url = 'https://microsoft.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(website_url)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

As of `selenium` `4.10.0` the driver manager is fully integrated, and will silently download drivers as needed. (Eg. On Mac/Linux, drivers are automatically downloaded to the `~/.cache/selenium` folder if not found on the PATH.) Slightly earlier versions of `selenium` had a beta of the driver manager.

Optionally now, if you want to specify a PATH, you can do so via the `service` arg:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_DRIVER")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

But specifying the `executable_path` is optional now (and must be done via the `service` arg).

Comment: Was this `Selenium Manager` to handle browser drivers not already part of selenium since `Selenium v4.6.0`? What is new in `v4.10.0`?

Comment: Selenium manager is fully integrated now. Lots of changes to args: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

Answer (score 1):

*No more mandatory*.

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v10.x*** and onwards you don't need to explicitly mention the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) location through `Service` object or `executable_path` key.

The reason behind, incase *ChromeDriver* is not found as per your system's *PATH* settings it will automatically get downloaded using the new *Selenium Driver Manager* which is fully integrated within Selenium now.

- Minimum code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49197/devtools/browser/07e3d01a-32db-482a-a1e0-dc489efcc03c
  ```

---

### tl; dr

References:

- [Remove deprecated code in driver classes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12030)
- [Commit - Remove deprecated code in driver classes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e)

Comment: Was this `Selenium Manager` to handle browser drivers not already part of selenium since `Selenium v4.6.0`? What is new in `v4.10.0`?